# Selenium not finding elements on the subsequent pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My script works fine till i go to a new page (using click()). After that nothing works.

```
driver.get("https://intranet.cb.amrita.edu")
delay = 5 # seconds
try:
    aums = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'ASE, ASCOM, MSW - Students')))
    aums.click()
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
delay = 5 # seconds
try:
    uname = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))
    uname.send_keys("abc")
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

This doesn't work and says something like no such element found (for the username) . 
The same script with a few modifications, if I change the `driver.get("neededurl")` it works. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the correct code format to your question, so it will be easier to read. You can refer to more of our guidelines here: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: Also, you probably need to print the exception that appears in your ```try/exception``` stages, so you can give more tools to answer your question.